# What causes the 'float' object is not callable" error in my code

Tags: python

I am trying to learn opps python

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, fname, lnama, salary,):
        self.fname = fname
        self.lnama = lnama
        self.salary = salary
        self.increment = 1.5

    def increment(self):
        self.salary = self.salary * self.increment

harry = Employee('harry','jacson',44000)
manoj = Employee('manoj','pagal',76000)

print(harry.salary)   
harry.increment()
```

I get the following eror:

> 44000
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "classes.py", line 17, in 
>         harry.increment()
>       TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

I can't figure out why.

Comment: Looks like `harry.increment` is a float instead of a function.

Comment: typo: change `self.increment` to `self._increment`

Answer (score 3):

The issue comes from assigning `self.increment` in your `__init__` and having a `self.increment()` method. You can solve this by having a `self._increment` property instead.

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, fname, lnama, salary,):
        self.fname = fname
        self.lnama = lnama
        self.salary = salary
        self._increment = 1.5

    def increment(self):
        self.salary = self.salary * self._increment

harry = Employee('harry','jacson',44000)
manoj = Employee('manoj','pagal',76000)

print(harry.salary)   
harry.increment()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has both variables and functions with the same name. You need to replace the name one of the two.

On your code, `increment` is a variable of type float.

```
class Employee(object):

    def __init__(self, fname, lnama, salary):
        self.fname = fname
        self.lnama = lnama
        self.salary = salary
        self.increment = 1.5

    def get_increment(self):
        self.salary = self.salary * self.increment

harry = Employee('harry','jacson',44000)
manoj = Employee('manoj','pagal',76000)

print(harry.salary)   
harry.get_increment()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your program increment is name of variable as well as member function which is ambiguous to python.

Either you should change the variable name or function name.

Answer (score 0):

Since python functions are objects (hint: everything in python is an object), there's no distinct namespace for "data" attributes and "function" (methods) attributes, so you can't have both a method and an instance attribute by the same name. Given attribute resolution rules, the instance attribute has precedence over the method, so `harry.increment` is resolved as `harry.__dict__["increment"]` (the instance attribute), not as `Employee.__dict__["increment"]` (the method).

The solution here is plain simple: you have to rename either the instance attribute or the method.